# Why is not live server extension is not working in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Live Server extension is not working in VScode. I have tried uninstalling and again installing both VSCode and the live server extension but it is not working. The error message is "Application not found". Attaching the image containing an error message.

[image: Image of error]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your default browser from **system settings** then try again.
This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the default browser from system setting and then run the live server.
Then it will work.